# Is there a way where we add scope to Sentry and add tracing information in Sentry-Java.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sentry

I am trying to add request id tracing when I capture an exception in Sentry-Java. In the official doc, only code samples for javascript is given.

Is this feature available for Sentry-Java..?

https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/tracing/

Answer (score 2):

Tracing is an experiment that Sentry ([see the forum](https://forum.sentry.io/t/sentry-tracing/6681)) is doing at the moment. It's pretty new and so far it's only part of the JavaScript and Python SDKs. The reason these two SDKs were picked is that Sentry uses both of them and will be dogfooding this feature.

This is all still [changing a lot](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/pull/372).

That means at this point `sentry.java` doesn't support tracing but once the broader support arrives this will be communicated. Likely via [the blog](https://blog.sentry.io/) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/getsentry).